# How to fill square / rect box using Apache and PDFBox

Tags: apache, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I have already written a java code, which fills only the first box/square. How can we programmatically fill all the squares or boxes in pdf ?

Example pdf
https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/wcm/connect/d7d1a212-f8df-45b1-a9ee-c09454a5b423/dmv14.pdf?MOD=AJPERES

```
public class Main {

    public void setField(PDDocument pdfDocument, String name, String value) throws IOException {
        PDDocumentCatalog docCatalog = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog();
        PDAcroForm acroForm = docCatalog.getAcroForm();
        acroForm.getFields().stream().forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.toString()));
        PDField field = acroForm.getField(name);
        System.out.println(field.getFullyQualifiedName());

        COSDictionary dict = ((PDField) field).getCOSObject();
        COSString defaultAppearance = (COSString) dict.getDictionaryObject(COSName.DA);

        if (field != null) {
            if (field instanceof PDCheckBox) {
                field.setValue("Yes");
            } else if (field instanceof PDComboBox) {
                field.setValue(value);
            } else if (field instanceof PDListBox) {
                field.setValue(value);
            } else if (field instanceof PDRadioButton) {
                field.setValue(value);
            } else if (field instanceof PDTextField) {
                field.setValue(value);
            }
            acroForm.flatten();
        } else {
            System.err.println("No field found with name:" + name);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Main setter = new Main();
        setter.setField(args);
    }

    private void setField(String[] args) throws IOException {
        PDDocument pdf = null;
        try {
            Main example = new Main();
            pdf = PDDocument.load(new File("dmv14.pdf"));
            example.setField(pdf, "first name", "JAT");
            pdf.setAllSecurityToBeRemoved(true);
            pdf.save("dmv14.pdf");
        } finally {
            if (pdf != null) {
                pdf.close();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will print out a message telling how to use this example.
     */
    private static void usage() {
        System.err.println("usage: org.apache.pdfbox.examples.interactive.form.SetField <pdf-file> <field-name> <field-value>");
    }
}
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Btw you're only calling `example.setField(pdf, "first name", "JAT");` why do you expect it would fill other fields too?

Comment: Which part of this question is actually relevant to the Apache HTTP server?